# Marking cursor Clicks/Taps/Double Taps in Android Studio Screen Recorder

Tags: android, android-screen, screen-recording, android-screen-pinning

Android Screen Recorder is a great tool for capturing the Android Screen but is there a way to highlight the clicks and Taps as well while we navigate the App on the Android Phone/Emulator screen?

Answer (score 26):

You can do that by going to your emulator settings and activate developer mode:

Open Settings on the Android device.
Scroll to the very bottom of the menu and select ‘About phone’.
Scroll to the very bottom of the menu and select ‘Build number’ repeatedly. After the 7th or 8th click you should see a message telling you that you are a developer.
Click back to return to the main Settings menu.
There should be a new ‘Developer Options’ option above to ‘About phone’ option. Select ‘Developer Options’.
Under the ‘Input’ heading there is a ‘Show touches’ or 'Show taps' option. Selecting this will show all touch events on the screen including pinch to zoom gestures and so on.

Detailed answer here: [Enabling ‘show touches’ in Android screen](https://medium.theuxblog.com/enabling-show-touches-in-android-screen-recordings-for-user-research-cc968563fcb9)

Comment: Thanks - I wish there was a way to make to make the touch zone larger/more obvious